# How to access dynamic variable in js?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I am trying to access dynamic variable in js. This is how I am creating dynamic variable:

```
var marker{{$working_order->user_id}} = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: address,
                map: map,
            });
```

after that when any event happen I want to call that variable again like this:

```
console.log('marker'+data.user_id)
```

But this time it is not variable it is just a string is there any way I can access it as variable?

Comment: Maybe keep it in an object or map keyed by user id?

Comment: Don't create dynamic variables. Use an object literal with dynamic property names, or even a `Map`, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const marker = {};

marker[$working_order->user_id] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: address,
                map: map,
            });

console.log(marker[$working_order->user_id]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!